# Apache Airflow Init Db

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, airflow, psycopg2

I am trying to initialize a database for my project which is based on using apache airflow. I am not too familiar with what happened but I changed my value from airflow.cfg file to sql_alchemy_conn =postgresql+psycopg2:////Users/gabeuy/airflow/airflow.db. Then when I saved the changes and ran the command airflow db init, the error occurred and did not allow me to run the db.

I tried looking up different ways to change it, ensured that I had Postgres and psycopg installed but it still resulted in an error when I ran the command. I was expecting it to run so that I could access the airflow db local host with the DAGs. [error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WybuY.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your `sql_alchemy_conn` is pointing to a local file path (indicating a SQLite DB), but the protocol is indicating a PostgreSQL DB. The error is telling you it's missing a password, which is required by PostgreSQL.

For PostgreSQL, the expected URL format is:

```
postgresql+psycopg2://<user>:<password>@<host>/<db>
```

And for a SQLite DB, the expected URL format is:

```
sqlite:////<path/to/airflow.db>
```

A SQLite DB is convenient for testing purposes. A SQLite DB is stored as a single file on your computer which makes it easy to set up (`airflow db init` will generate the file if it doesn't exist). A PostgreSQL DB takes a bit more work to set up, but is generally advised for a production scenario.

For more information about Airflow database configuration, see: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html.

And for more information about `airflow db` CLI commands, see: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#db.